# Applying to a recruiter company

Tags: software-industry, rejection, recruiting

I applied to a position of a recruiting company and I had all the basic requirements and a little experience to an ability that was considered as a plus. After my application, I took an automated reply that my application received. The strange is that after 15 minutes!!!!! I took also a rejection answer.
The position was relative to the software engineer and mathematics.

I am wondering what about the recruiting companies, have you ever heard anything like this? Have you ever been helped by these companies?

Thanks in advance for sharing your opinion.

Comment: Sounds like they just managed to read your application as soon as they received it, or didn't look at it at all. Any suggestion that the rejection email was automated?

Comment: I'd take that as a positive. This is a lead I don't have to worry about and chase up on after 2 weeks. Recruiting companies _must_ place some people now and then, or they'd be out of business. Now regarding your question, I have VTC because I believe sharing opinion on the concept of recruiting companies is too subjective.

Comment: @Kozaky I think it is a template rejection, but I believed that at least they would see the cv. I think they didn't look it at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some companies have automated text-recognition software scanning PDF/Word/text document to look for keywords.

It is possible that your application did not include the keywords the company was looking for and did not pass stage 1 (triage).